# How to detect that a puppet run is complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, puppet, openstack

I need a way to detect that puppet has finished an initial run ( successfully ), so I can wait before launching other actions when spinning up machines on AWS EC2 and/or OpenStack.
  How can I check this?

Some ideas floated so far are:

1. have puppet touch a file when finished ( successfully ), I can then just watch for that file
2. have puppet write a fact when finished (successfully ),  I can check facts through mcollective. 
                ( Not sure if writing to puppet db from within a puppet run is even possible )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/var/lib/puppet/state/puppetdlock
/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml
/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml
```

These are the files you want to check.

The lock file is set if puppetd is currently running.
State and last_run_summary can be used to see if past runs have succeeded or not.

See also this serverfault question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/463231/check-if-puppet-agent-is-up-to-date

Comment: If your using Puppet Enterprise these files are normally found under /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state.  Use puppet config print vardir to find the directory if you installed at a custom location

Answer (score 1):

I have try it on CentOS 6.4

If you run Server/Client mode, check the file exist:

/var/lib/puppet/state/agent_catalog_run.lock

If you run it in standalone, I don't find there exist a lock file. Maybe you need to parse the log file for this item "Finished catalog run in xxx seconds"